# Why and how are the email click counter links encoded

Tags: encoding, html-email

When you check a link from a few promotion emails, you can find the links not directly linking to the desired content, but there is a redirect to a click counter (possible an event logger API of a user behaviour analytics tool), and then it will redirect you to the expected target site.

Examples:
Link from a Monster Job Alert:
https://click.emails.monster.com/?qs=ced129cad79732a77414ba5d0e289bca8a05fbc61b40a663e145052adfc4b42af7d7adce8730027e65001dbfebd6acf50f94f3833b0cc6ef7077b0b950413c1c

Link from a Google Suite Newsletter:
https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AD-FnEygvQpl-q8YrvQOEm9T1x-S0sP0qAe8wj1Y1gyyXnmVt2KlIB7PbnttejuXVVmEcpKlkkfL0OaDNCy3v5BuogSsEZEuRXBiTFp0-slPrvq71ces9JcTff-A8guSCF95RHslNJGFRbsM-Lvaq2NHE5u0bo4XUQ

Link from a Product Hunt newsletter:
http://links.producthunt.com/lnk/BAAAAPOltm8AAcgxW3wAAATsm4wAAAAIijYAAAAAAAYklQBfIX8muzFnHMm5TsS8vQbi2aAZ3wAF1QU/5/wrattIJVpsbnIM0UoGFsOA/aHR0cHM6Ly9tb25kYXkuY29tL2xwL3Byb2plY3RtYW5hZ2VtZW50L2J1bmRsZS8_dXRtX3NvdXJjZT1tYiZ1dG1fY2FtcGFpZ249cHJvZHVjdGh1bnQmdXRtX21lZGl1bT0lNUJuYW1lJTIwb2YlMjBwbGFjZW1lbnQlNUQ

So, my question is: does anyone know what is this encoding in the URL? What could be the reason to encode the redirect URL in a way like this?

Comment: Now I'm thinking it is probably an encrypted string which will be decrypted by the link tracked endpoint. Maybe to make sure any sensitive info (e.g. userID) cannot be found easily.

Comment: The tracking servers at Oracle/responsys e.g., need to be able to keep track of millions of links, so even two links with same url and parameters needs to be different for the backend to keep track of. So maybe its just a way to make it unique.